# Interpolation and Extrapolation using Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to conduct multiple-dimension interpolation and extrapolation using scipy.  I already have the code that can interpolate more than 3-dimension data as follows (This code is from [scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator hangs indefinitely on large data sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618971/scipy-interpolate-linearndinterpolator-hangs-indefinitely-on-large-data-sets)).

```
def interp3(x, y, z, v, xi, yi, zi, method='linear'):
    q = (x, y, z)
    qi = (xi, yi, zi)
    for j in range(3):
        v = interp1d(q[j], v, axis=j, kind=method)(qi[j])
    return v
```

or,

```
def interp4(x, y, z, z2, v, xi, yi, zi, zi2, method='linear'):
    q = (x, y, z, z2)
    qi = (xi, yi, zi, zi2)
    for j in range(4):
        v = interp1d(q[j], v, axis=j, kind=method)(qi[j])
    return v
```

This code, however, only treats interpolation, does not covers extrapolation. I think scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline can provide linear extrapolation for 1-D data, but does not provide the "axis" option that is used in interp1d. Is there a good method to conduct both linear extrapolation and interpolation for more than 3-dimensional data?

Comment: This question hasn't much to do with MATLAB, you should remove the tag.

Comment: Have you looked at BivariateSpline? It would seem to do precisely what you want, fitting a 2D spline to (x,y,z) data in one go...

Comment: BivariateSpline would correspond to 2-D spline. I would like to calculate 3-D, 4-D, even 5-D interpolation and extrapolation with one function.